# Divide values from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, php-5.6

I have this array

```
$a = [
     0 => [
         'period'     => '2017/2018',
         'product'    => 'AM',
         'quantity_1' => 20,
         'quantity'   => 25,
     ],
     1 => [
         'period'     => '2018/2019',
         'product'    => 'AM',
         'quantity_1' => 12,
         'quantity'   => 19,
     ],
     2 => [
         'period'     => '2017/2018',
         'product'    => 'DC',
         'quantity_1' => 20,
         'quantity'   => 25,
     ], 
     3 => [
         'period'     => '2018/2019',
         'product'    => 'DC',
         'quantity_1' => 8,
         'quantity'   => 10,
     ]
]
```

The idea is to divide values by period and by product, in this case we have 2 products 'AM' && 'DC'. So divide values fom `2018/2019` to `2017/2018` for product `AM` and for product `DC`. I need to get the result like this :

```
$result = [
      0 => [
            'product'     => 'AM'
            'quantity_1'  => 12/20 = 0.6
            'quantity_2'  => 19/25 = 0.76
      ],
      1 => [
            'product'     => 'DC'
            'quantity_1'  => 8/20 = 0.4
            'quantity_2'  => 10/25 = 0.4
      ]
]
```

I tried with foreach but I think exist some other easy ways to do that. If you have some ideas I will appreciate this. Thank you for your time.

I tried like this :

```
$i = 0;
    foreach ($results as $result){
        $result[] = [
            'product'       => $result['product'],
            'tonnes_prod'   => $results[$i+1]['quantity_1'] / $results[$i]['quantity_1']
        ];
        $i++;
    }
```

But I get the error : `#message: "Notice: Undefined offset: 28"`

Comment: `foreach` is totally fine.

Comment: @u_mulder I edited the question with my foreach

Comment: Is this part a string? `19/25 = 0.76` looks hard to use

Comment: No, the result should be : `0.76`

Comment: So what is `19/25`?

Comment: @Andreas Probably to explain where the 0.76 was from.

Comment: @JonStirling exactly

Comment: Ok.. then I have a suggestion. Why not make it associative with year or the 19/25 thing. It seems as it will be a message to sort out once the code has done its job. With this small array it will probably be fine, but add another 10 years of data and it will be messy, I think.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/niICu - Do you want like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remake your array first, and then calculate the result

```
$temp = [];
foreach ($a as $x){
    $temp[$x['product']][$x['period']] = $x;
}

$result = [];
foreach ($temp as $key => $res){
    $result[] = [
        'product'       => $key,
        'quantity_1'   => $res['2018/2019']['quantity_1'] / $res['2017/2018']['quantity_1'],
        'quantity_2'   => $res['2018/2019']['quantity'] / $res['2017/2018']['quantity'],
    ];
}
```

[**demo**](https://3v4l.org/aGU5D)